# Adding image to button using Emotion css

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, emotion

I want to style two buttons: Up and Down with an image using emotion css but unable to do so. Currently, I am normally styling my elements within a function. How can I achieve this using emotion css?
I followed https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction but I am unable to implement it the right way.

```
    import up from "../img/up.png";

    function PostButton(props) {
    let style = {
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    background: `url(${up})`,
    paddingRight: 24,
    paddingTop: 26,
    paddingLeft: 26,
    paddingBottom: 26.6
    };
    return (
    <button style={style} onClick={() => props.handleClick()}>{props.background}</button>
    );
    }

//I have written similar code for PostButton2


function Post(props) {
    return (
    <div>
                    <Up >
                        <PostButton src={"../images/up.png"} handleClick= . 
     {props.incrementScore} />
                    </Up>                    >

                    <Down >
                        <PostButton2 src={"../images/down.png"} 
 handleClick{props.decrementScore} />
                    </Down>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that src property holds the background image, I think you need to update background to use the prop like so:

```
background: `url(${props.src})`,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use src prop as path to image.

```
// First way, with css from emotion/react

/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/react'

const PostButton = ({ background, handleClick, src }) => (
  <button css={css`
    background: ${`no-repeat url(${src})`};
    padding: 26px 24px 26.6px 26px;
  `} 
  onClick={handleClick}>{background}</button>
)

// Second way, with css from emotion/css

import React from 'react'
import { css } from '@emotion/css'

const PostButton = ({ background, handleClick, src }) => (
  <button className={css`
    background: ${`no-repeat url(${src})`};
    padding: 26px 24px 26.6px 26px;
  `} 
  onClick={handleClick}>{background}</button>
)

// Third way, with css from emotion/css, but pass styles as object

import React from 'react'
import { css } from '@emotion/css'

const PostButton = ({ background, handleClick, src }) => (
  <button className={css({
    background: `no-repeat url(${src})`,
    padding: '26px 24px 26.6px 26px'
  })} 
  onClick={handleClick}>{background}</button>
)
```